# UIPageViewController Gesture overriding my UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a UIPageViewController to swipe views vertically. I have 3 different views, the on on the middle holds a UITableViewController.

If I use a mapkit view on te middle, the mapkit overrides all UIPageViewController touches, and works perfectly. The same thing doesnt happen with tables. Sometimes touch scrolls table, something it scrolls the pageviewcontroller.

Anyone know a simple way to bring the tableview gestures to top, overriding the pageview touch?

(I did setup a touch handled and check if touch is inside table, overriding pageview touch this way, but its slow and not a100% solution)

(mapkit view behaviour would be perfect)
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

my mac not at hand right now and i can't test, but u can try to play with two flags in Attributes inspector: "delays content touches" and "cancellable content touches"

Comment: @ChristopherRivera not really. In the end I found a workaround for that specific project. The bug happens when the table reached top or bottom. So in order to avoid it, I dont let user reach end/top of the table. I check for content size and always return the table position with -1 on scroll. This way it scrolls perfectly. It's not an elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: You can use this third party library which will allow the swipe gesture of the menu to have president over the uipageviewcontroller swipe

https://github.com/WinterKirk/MKSlidingTableViewCell

the important thing is that your whole view shouldnt only have these kind of cells cause then the uipageviewcontroller wont be able to swipe

but it works great in situations where you lets say have an image and comments under it and people should be able to delete the comments but swipe to the next pic on all other cells